# Compiling error with MPFR package on mac

Tags: c++, mpfr

When I try to compile the newly installed package MPFR I get the following error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mpfr_init2", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I use Codelite on a macbook pro and I think I successfully installed the package using the instruction on the website.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information given, I suspect that you are not linking the MPFR library during the linking phase of main.cpp. What is the exact command you are using?

Make sure that `-lmpfr` is passed at the end of the clang++ command, like so:

```
clang++ main.cpp -lmpfr
```

or:

```
clang++ main.cpp -c
clang++ main.o -lmpfr
```

If libmpfr.so is installed in a nonstandard place, then you need to tell the compiler where, using the `-L` option:

```
clang++ main.cpp -L"$MPFR_PATH" -lmpfr
```

or:

```
clang++ main.cpp -c
clang++ main.o -L"$MPFR_PATH" -lmpfr
```

If not, then please provide more information.